# Problems with alignment of a square root containing a fraction next to a square root in a denominator

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, alignment

I am trying to make the bottoms of the two square roots align, but I can't figure out how. I tried using the `\strut` command, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
%       BEGIN EQUATION MODE WITH LABEL
\newcommand{\beql}[1]{\begin{equation}\label{#1}}
%       END EQUATION MODE WITH A PERIOD
\newcommand{\eeqp}{\;\;\;.\end{equation}}

\beql{Qt}Q=\frac{1}{R}\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4L}{CR^2}}}\eeqp
```

And here is it's output. You can see how wonky the equation looks.
[image: Q factor]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you (a) switch to inline-fraction notation in the third denominator term and (b) insert `\myphantom` instructions in the first two denominator terms, where `\myphantom` is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand\myphantom{\vphantom{\sqrt{R^2}}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand\myphantom{\vphantom{\sqrt{R^2}}}
\setlength\textwidth{3in}
\begin{document}
Before:
\begin{equation}
Q=\frac{1}{R} \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4L}{CR^2}}}
\end{equation}

After:
\begin{equation}
Q=\frac{1}{R\myphantom} \sqrt{\frac{L}{C\myphantom}}\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4L/(CR^2)}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That phantom command is magic!